# CSS3 transition & transform is not working well on class removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I've made some nice hamburger effect which is pretty common these days over the websites in mobile navigation bar.

So when someone click the hamburger it turn the X perfectly (when adding a "open" class) but when the class removed the animation is changing weirdly, please watch the effect at the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="hamburger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#hamburger {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

#hamburger span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
}

#hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, -moz-transform 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, -o-transform 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease 0.3s;
}

#hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 7px;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 14px;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, -moz-transform 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, -o-transform 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease 0.3s;
}


#hamburger.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 7px;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
}

#hamburger.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#hamburger.open span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 7px;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hamburger').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phhkL4bu/4/

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Please show your code so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Just added, sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can correct the removal animation by doing the following:

- Set the forward transition's setting within the `.open` selector. When the `.open` class is added, the `opacity` of second child is transitioned for a duration of 0.3s without any delay. At the same time, the `top` position of the other 2 children is also being transitioned. Then after a `0.3s` delay, the `transform` of the 1st and 3rd children is transitioned. This gives the effect of the top and the bottom bar moving down and then rotating.
- Set its exact reverse as `transition` setting in the default selector. That is,make the `transform` on the 1st and 3rd child transition immediately with a `0.3s` duration while the `top` of these two children and the `opacity` of the 2nd child are transitioned after a delay of `0.3s`. This setting will apply when the element loses the `.open` class and so,will produce the reverse effect.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hamburger').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
#hamburger {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
#hamburger span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
}
#hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease;
}
#hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 7px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
#hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 14px;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease;
}
#hamburger.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 7px;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease 0.3s;
}
#hamburger.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#hamburger.open span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 7px;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="hamburger">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```